# Get last record with criteria api

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

everyone.
My task is to get the last added record from my database. Since the last of the records in the database has the maximum id, I wrote a method like this, but it always returns null to me.

```
@Override
    public Address getLast() {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Address> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Address.class);
        Root<Address> root = criteriaQuery.from(Address.class);
        criteriaQuery
                .select(root)
                .orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Address_.id)));
        TypedQuery<Address> findAllSizes = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return findAllSizes.getResultStream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All works fine. All I needed to add was add @Transactional on the method which calls the specified method